# Getting Powershell to report a file's size to a CSV and keep adding to it instead of replacing the data

Tags: powershell, csv

I am attempting to basically create a Powershell script that basically just looks at an Access database file size on the server, adds the file size and exact date and time to a CSV, then saves it.

I just want a running report of the size, and I am going to have it scheduled to run every hour. I have no idea how to get it to just ADD to the CSV instead to create a new CSV every time. Here is what I have so far:

```
$file = "\\location\file.mdb"
$Header = 'Name','Size','Time'
$Data = Import-Csv "\\location\REPORT.csv" -Delim ',' -Header $Header
$CSV = "\\location\REPORT.csv"
$A = Get-Date -UFormat '%B-%d-%Y %r'
$NewRow = "Name,Size,Time"
$NewRow | Add-Content -Path $CSV
Get-ChildItem -Path $file -Recurse -Force | ForEach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = "$([int]($_.length / 1mb)) MB"
        Time = $A
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "\\location\REPORT.csv" -Delim ',' -En UTF8 -NoType
```

It creates the CSV, but it just overwrites with a new line instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Use [`Export-Csv -Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1#example-6--export-and-append-objects-to-a-csv-file) :)

Comment: Also, you can omit `-Delim ','` because Export-Csv uses the comma as delimiter by default

Comment: OK, I added the "-Append" flag and removed the "-Delim ','" flag as suggested above. But now it adds headers above each row every time instead of JUST new data each time. What do I do to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Most commands that dump to a file like `Export-[Type]` and `Out-File` support the `-Append` flag:

```
Export-Csv -Path "\\location\REPORT.csv" -Delim ',' -En UTF8 -NoType -Append
```

Comment: OK, I added the "-Append" flag and removed the "-Delim ','" flag as suggested above. But now it adds headers above each row every time instead of JUST new data each time. What do I do to change that?

Comment: @JoshB. Remove these two lines, they are not needed: 
`$NewRow = "Name,Size,Time"
$NewRow | Add-Content -Path $CSV`

Comment: If I don't at least have the "$NewRow | Add-Content -Path $CSV" line, I get an error that says "Export-Csv : The process cannot access the file '<file>' because it is 
being used by another process."

Comment: Excel was hanging in the background of the system I was showing the person this sheet with. Force quit and that error goes away. Nevermind, it works now! THANK YOU!!!